# MVC URL structure

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing, actionlink

Have the following link in Index.cshtml:

```
 @Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { clientId = item.ClientId ,      overrideId=item.OverrideId})
```

and route as:

```
 routes.MapRoute(
          name: "Edit",
           url: "{controller}/{action}/{clientId}/{overrideId}",
          defaults: new { controller = "ClientOverride", action = "Edit", clientId =       UrlParameter.Optional, overrideId = UrlParameter.Optional }
       );
```

When redirect occurs from Index to Edit, the following URL is created:

.../clientoverride/edit/6?overrideId=1

while I would expect something like:

.../clientoverride/edit/6/1

Why so inconsistent URL is created? What can I do to make it look like a tree structure with clientoverride/edit/6/1 at the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Put this on top of all the rules used for `clientoverride` controller:-

```
    routes.MapRoute(
         name: "Edit",
          url: "{controller}/{action}/{clientId}/{overrideId}",
         defaults: new { controller = "ClientOverride", action = "Edit", clientId = UrlParameter.Optional, overrideId = UrlParameter.Optional }
      );
```

As your default route map is forming the url in this format`/clientoverride/edit/6?overrideId=1`. So, after changing the sequence it will solve your problem.

Comment: thank you - it worked like a charm: put this on top of routes; got URL as: .../clientoverride/Edit/6/1

Answer (score 0):

Try using `Html.RouteLink` instead of `Html.ActionLink`.

For links to routes that have more than one argument, you're better placed using `@Html.RouteLink` as it's for custom routes.

In your instance, you'd use `@Html.RouteLink("Edit", "Edit", new { clientId = item.ClientId, overrideId = item.OverrideId})`

The above example uses `Html.RouteLink(LINKTEXT, ROUTENAME, VALUES)`

The reason you're getting the URL you're seeing is that `Html.ActionLink` always assumes the default route format so any additional parameters end up getting turned into a query string.

Make sure your custom route is above the default route too.